# $ \dim_K\operatorname{Im}(T^2) =\dim_K\operatorname{Im}(T) \implies \operatorname{Im}(T) \cap \operatorname{Ker}(T) = \{0\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need some help here...

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$, and $T: V \to W$ a linear transformation. Prove that if $$ dim_KV \lt \infty \ \ \text{and} \ \ \dim_K\operatorname{Im}(T^2) = \dim_K\operatorname{Im}(T)$$
>   then $$\operatorname{Im}(T) \cap \operatorname{Ker}(T) = \{0\}$$

This is what I made so far.

Let $x \in \operatorname{Im}(T) \cap \operatorname{Ker}(T)$,where T is linear operator.
Then $T(x)=0$ and $x=T(v)$ for some $v \in V$

$0 = T(x) = T(T(v)) = T^2(v) \implies v\in \operatorname{Ker}(T^2)$

My intention is to reach $x=0$, but I'm stuck at this point. I also deduced, via dimension theorem, that $\dim_K \operatorname{Ker}(T) = \dim_K \operatorname{Ker}(T^2) $ but I don't know where it can help. Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: You have $\ker(T) \subset \ker(T^2)$. Now use the dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank-nullity theorem says
\begin{align}
\dim V&=\dim\operatorname{Im}(T)+\dim\operatorname{Ker}(T) \\
\dim V&=\dim\operatorname{Im}(T^2)+\dim\operatorname{Ker}(T^2)
\end{align}
Next use the fact that
$$
\operatorname{Ker}(T)\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(T^2)
$$
to conclude that
$$
\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\operatorname{Ker}(T^2)
$$

Comment: Oh, I did not know that $\operatorname{Ker}(T)\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(T^2)$.

Comment: @Карпатський If $T(v)=0$, then $T^2(v)=0$. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I haven't done linear algebra for a while, and I'm trying to refresh my memory. How exactly can we conclude that $\operatorname{Ker(T)}=\operatorname{Ker(T^2)}$? Does it follow from the fact that their dimensions are equal and the fact that the one is subset of the other implies that they live in the same space?

Comment: @K.Power Since $\ker(T)\subseteq\ker(T^2)$, when we show the former has the same dimension as the latter, we conclude they're equal (take a basis of $\ker(T)$: it has the number of elements needed to be a basis of $\ker(T^2)$).

Comment: @egreg Ok thanks I understand that.